# How can I iterate over specific elements in HTML file and replace them?

Tags: python, html

I need to do a seemingly simple thing in Python which turned out to be quite complex. What I need to do is:

1. Open an HTML file.
2. Match all instances of a specific HTML element, for example `table`.
3. For each instance, extract the element as a string, pass that string to an external command which will do some modifications, and finally replace the original element with a new string returned from the external command.

I can't simply do a `re.sub()`, because in each case the replacement string is different and based on the original string.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).  Likely, you'd want to do something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

tables = soup.find_all( 'table' )
for table in tables:
    contents = str( table.contents )
    new_contents = transform( contents )
    table.replaceWith( new_contents )
```

Alternatively, you may be looking for something closer to [`soup.replace_with`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with)

**EDIT:** Updated to the eventual solution.

Comment: Tried that, but it's not so simple unfortunately, unless I'm getting it wrong. The string property only works if the element contains a string, whereas a table has some more markup under it. So table.string returns "None".

Comment: my bad.  You want the [`contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) property.

Comment: Cheers! In the end, this is what worked:


`   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

    tables = soup.find_all( 'table' )
    for table in tables:
        contents = str( table.contents )
        new_contents = transform( contents )
        table.replaceWith( new_contents )
`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to do this.

Although for what you need, something simpler like [lxml.etree](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that parsing HTML via BeautifulSoup or any other such parses gets complex as you need to parse different pages, with different structure which sometimes are not well-formed, use javascript manipulation etc. Best solution in this case is to directly access the browser DOM and modify and query nodes. You can easily do that in a headless browser like [phanotomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) 
e.g. here is a phantomjs script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.content = '<html><body><table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table></html>';
page.evaluate(function () {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
    for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        elems[i].innerHTML = '!'+elems[i].innerHTML+'!';
    }
});
console.log(page.content);
phantom.exit();
```

It changes all `td` text and output is

```
<html><head></head><body><table><tbody><tr><td>!1!</td><td>!2!</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```